# Mandrill queue in php

Tags: php, symfony, message-queue, mandrill

Have you any idea how to control the queue of Mandrill send emails in PHP ? 
Well, I'm using Symfony as a Framework, & this is my send function in the Mandrill class :

```
public function sendMandrill()
{
    $listTo = array();
    foreach ($this->contacts as $contact)
    {
        $listTo[] = [
            'name' => $contact->getFname(),
            'email' => $contact->getEmail()
        ];
    }
    var_dump($listTo);


    $email = array(
        'html' => $this->message->getBodyHtml(),
        'text' => $this->message->getBodyText(),
        'subject' => $this->message->getSubject(),
        'from_email' => $this->apiDom,
        'from_name' => $this->message->getFromName(),
        'to' => $listTo,
        "preserve_recipients"=> false,
    );

    $this->senderAPI = new \Mandrill("$this->apiKey");

    return $this->senderAPI->messages->send($email);

}
```

Now, I want to create a function so I can pause the sending for a while so I can change such things, then resume it whenever I want or may be to stop it at all !
which mean there will be 3 functions as following :

```
public function pauseMandrill()
    {
               ...
    }

    public function resumeMandrill()
    {
               ...
    }

    public function stopMandrill()
    {
               ...
    }
```